# Missing color icon

Tags: android, colors

I'm new to Android Studio and I'm noticing that the the color icon next to the line is not shown, does anyone know what's going on. Here in the picture is line 14 and 23, [img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lyD8b.png).
Also it was still with me last night when i was doing my homework but after like 20-30 mins and it's gone. I must've done something wrong and didnt realize about it

I've looked up on android website, chatgpt,.. and no solution

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: so sorry about bad writing, there are 2 pictures to show the problem, first one is mine and is random person's 
https://imgur.com/pPgQLzK 
https://imgur.com/undefined

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling the gutter icons.

1. Right-Click on the gutter beside the line number. Go to `Appearance` -> `Configure Gutter Icons...`
   [image]
2. Check the option `Show gutter icons` and Click `Apply` -> `OK`
   [image]

Comment: hey, thanks for giving up ur time and helping me but unfortunately, that option is already enabled. My apologize but i forgot to mention that last night when i was practising, it was still be there but after about 20-30 mins it has  gone disappeared. I must've done something wrong by mistake, could you help me sir